# UIRefreshControl not calling refresh function only for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol, iphone-6

Here is my code for pulldown refresh in `viewDidLoad`

```
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.blue
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Loading")
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    scrollview.refreshControl = refreshControl
} else {
    scrollview.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

here is my refresh function

```
func refresh() {
print("Pull down refresh called")
}
```

That works fine for all the devices except iPhone 6.
I have tested with iPhone 6 simulator-iOS 10.3
What will be the issue? And how to resolve that?

Comment: I believe iPhone model won't make difference, please post the OS version.

Comment: if you use `scrollview.refreshControl = refreshControl`   iOS 10 or higher it wil work or not

Comment: OS version iOS 10.3

Comment: the above code works fine for all the devices except iPhone 6

Comment: Do you use the refresh control in UITableViewController?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol: `Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a different context can result in undefined behavior.`